# KafkaItemWriter writing but not to default topic

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-kafka

Can someone post an example or help how i can use KafkaItemWriter to write java objects into non-default topic. Just like in SpringKafka we use KafkaTemplate.send(topicName, user) is there a way for kafkaItemWriter also? I do not want to write to default topic configured through properites file like spring.kafka.template.default-topic=topicName.
In my springBatch job i want to run to different batch jobs and like to write into two different topics.

Comment: `In my springBatch job i want to run to different batch jobs and like to write into two different topics.`: If you are going to use two different jobs, why don't you use two different writers each one configured for a separate topic?

Comment: Yes, i will write two different writers each one configured to two separate topics. I figured a way out to set topic name into writer using KafkaTemplate.setDefaultTopic method. Now in another writer i will set diff topic name. Thanks, I have one more question, in my requirement for two spring batch jobs, i have one reader, processor and writer and for another job, i want to use same reader but different processor and different writer because in both jobs reader is going to read data from same table from db and i do not want to make another call for reading same data.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure this is what you want or not.
But KafkaTemplate has method “setDefaultTopic” (https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaTemplate.html#setDefaultTopic(java.lang.String))

I think you can change default topic what you want by using setDefaultTopic before call KafakItemWriter step.